# Canadian Test Phone for Testing Use in USA

Tags: manual-testing, mobile, mobile-testing

I'm based in the USA and I need to do some manual testing of a mobile app. We have a lot of users that are based in Canada and we want to test various flows specific to Canadian users.

We've tried simulating this, but from what we've seen that doesn't work since the locale of the phone is tied to our native country of the US vs CAN.

Maybe I'm overcomplicating this issue, but what's the best approach here? Do I need to buy a phone and sim/esim from a Canadian retailer and have them set it up there in order for the phone to be natively Canadian, therefore allowing us to test in the US but as a Canadian user? Or is there an easier/better way to do this that maybe I'm overthinking?

Thanks in advance!
-Jack

Comment: How are you determining who is a Canadian user? Phone number? Geolocation? Location services?

I think the answer to that will determine your next step. If you need a Canadian number, get a Canadian number. Otherwise, either spoof your location or use a proxy to make it look like you're coming from Canada.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Can you add more specifics on what you've already tried? How have you simulated this? This can help to not get answers you've already tried. Also, what about those attempts failed? Maybe someone has seen similar errors before.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions from a fellow tester,

1. Use a VPN: You can use a Virtual Private Network (VPN) to change your IP address to a Canadian one. This can simulate a Canadian user, as your internet traffic will appear to be coming from Canada.
   Example: ExpressVPN, NordVPN, CyberGhost VPN
2. Test with Canadian Emulators: You can use Canadian emulators for mobile testing. Emulators are virtual devices that mimic the behavior of real devices. There are a variety of Canadian mobile device emulators available online that you can use to test the mobile app.
   Example: AWS Device Farm, Firebase Test Lab, Sauce Labs, Browserstack
3. Cloud Testing: Cloud testing allows you to run tests on real devices located in different regions, including Canada. Using cloud testing, you can test your mobile app on real Canadian devices without having to physically be in Canada.
   Example: Genymotion, Android Studio Emulator, Xamarin Test Cloud
4. Hire Canadian Beta Testers: Another approach is to hire beta testers from Canada. Beta testers are real users who test your mobile app and provide feedback. You can hire beta testers from different regions, including Canada, to test your app and provide feedback on the Canadian-specific features.
   Example services providers: UserTesting, BetaFamily, BetaBound, Crowd4test
5. Use a Test Automation Tool: Test automation tools like Appium, Espresso, and XCUITest allow you to write automated tests for your mobile app. You can use these tools to test the Canadian-specific features of your mobile app.
   Example: Appium, Espresso, XCUITest
6. Use a Localization Testing Service: Localization testing services can test your mobile app for different regions and languages, including Canada. These services specialize in testing mobile apps for regional and language-specific features.
   Example: OneSky, TestLodge, TestRail
7. Use a Device Cloud Provider: Device cloud providers like Sauce Labs, BrowserStack, and TestObject provide access to real devices located in different regions, including Canada. You can use these services to test your mobile app on real Canadian devices without having to physically be in Canada.
   Example: Sauce Labs, BrowserStack, TestObject
8. Buy a Canadian Phone: If all else fails, you can buy a Canadian phone and sim/esim from a Canadian retailer and use it for testing. This may not be the most cost-effective solution, but it can provide the most accurate simulation of a Canadian user.
   Example: Apple iPhone or Samsung Galaxy from a Canadian retailer.